# Write an input inside of a modal - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, modal-dialog

I can't write inside an input that is inside a modal. This modal is open after clicking a button.

The following is the link :
`https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2148268902-departamento-los-espinos-id-116373-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=eba8327b-85c0-4317-8c63-7c69c5b34e16`

First, with this function the button is click:

```
    def button_click(self, xpath):
        time.sleep(2)
        button = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, xpath)
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

The xpath of the button is the following:

`"/html/body/div[2]/div/button"`

Once the modal is open I try manipulating the input of the modal and write inside.
I  use the following function:

```
    def write_input(self, xpath, answer):
        time.sleep(2)
        winput = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, xpath)
        winput.send_keys(answer)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Try with this xpath:
`/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input`

Get the following error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"}`

The flow is Open link --> Click Button "Contactar" --> Modal is open with inputs

How can I find the elements inside the modal?

Comment: It's not clear what element you're trying to locate, because your absolute xpath doesn't exist. After clicking button no modal was opened for me. Please, clarify what input you're trying to find.

Comment: I am trying to get the first input of the modal. Do you click the modal before looking for the xpath? Because if not it wouldn't not appear
In the link there is a button called "Contactar". That open a modal with some inputs. I need to write on them and send.

Comment: What is the steps to reach that modal? Like: Open url -> click the button with name "buttonName" -> ...

Comment: The buttonName is "Contactar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button has debounce logic, assigned to it.
That means that click action would be succeed only after debounce was ended. That can be 1+ seconds (it depends on site implementation).

So clicking on the button after rendering wouldn't trigger modal. You need to wait for some time via dirty `time.sleep(2)` or more or implement retry logic `click_with_retry`.

And try to avoid absolute xPath. Your resource has unique and readable attributes that can be used to build unique locators.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def click_and_wait_for_modal_with_retry(driver, max_retries, button_locator, by, dialog_locator):
    retries = 0
    while retries < max_retries:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(button_locator))
        button.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if len(driver.find_elements(by, dialog_locator)) > 0 and driver.find_elements(by, dialog_locator)[0].is_displayed():
            return
        retries += 1
    raise Exception('Retries exceeded')



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    'https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/MLC-2148268902-departamento-los-espinos-id-116373-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=eba8327b-85c0-4317-8c63-7c69c5b34e16')
consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'newCookieDisclaimerButton')))
consent.click()
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(consent))
click_and_wait_for_modal_with_retry(driver, 3, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type=primary] .andes-button__content'),
                                    By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.andes-modal__overlay')
dialog = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.andes-modal__overlay')))
wait = WebDriverWait(dialog, 10)
name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=name-input]')))
name.send_keys('name')
```

Comment: I use your approach and it works. 
Not with the same code because when I use it results in an exception.
Why xpath isn't the best way to look?

Comment: @raimundovaldivia xpath or css is a matter of habit. I prefer css for easy selectors and xpath for complicated. Css selectors are more readable for developers. The main my point was not to use absolute xpath, but use relative like `//button[@type='primary']//*[contains(@class, 'andes-button__content')]`

Comment: There was a small bug inside `click_and_wait_for_modal_with_retry` - I accidentally used `break` instead of `return`, I fixed snippet.